# Is there a way to globally change all the hyperlinks in all reports on a report server on SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, hyperlink, updates

We've just had one of our systems moved to a new server, along with 3600+ SSRS reports.  All these reports contain hyperlinks.  Unfortunately, none of these hyperlinks have been updated to point to the new server, and so are still opening items on the old server.

Instead of having to edit each hyperlink in each report, is there a way I can globally update the reports at the same time so that the hyperlinks point to the new server?

I thought running an update on the content field in the catalog table might do the job but apparently not from what I've been able to gather online.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: what i would do is make the hyperlinks as part of the dataset then just a matter of rendering values from the variable dynamically.

Comment: I think, in a ideal situation, that's what we would have done but that's not an option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, normally it would be better to store your hyperlinks in a dataset.
I dont think you can do that globally, because your hyperlink is embedded in your report.

You can open your report .rdl file in text editor. In the text editor you can search for your hyperlink and replace it with the new value (search & replace). Well this still has to be done per hand for each report.

On top, you can write a small program in C#, .NET, etc... in which you pass your old and new hyperlink (single or as datatable). The program basically, opens all the .rdl reports and apply the search & replace then close and safe it.

Comment: Thanks Strawberryshrub.  I was hoping to avoid having to edit the rdl files individually given the sheer volume of them.  Hence, ideally, I'm looking for something that would work like this code:

`use ReportServer
go
update dbo.catalog
 set content=convert(image,
    convert(varbinary(max),replace(
    CONVERT(varchar(Max),
    CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),Content)),'\\oldserver\','\\newserver\')))

where CONVERT(varchar(Max),CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),Content)) like '%\\oldserver\%'`